# Yogg-Saron Solo 10M and 25M fight resets / evade on entering Brain portal

Tags: azerothcore

I am running the latest Azerothcore with the module `mod-autobalance` in order to solo content.
When in Ulduar, Yogg-Saron opens up a `Brain portal` in Phase2 so you can enter and kill his brain. After killing the brain you should resurface using the portal near the brain.

The only problem is once I enter the brain portal and want to run to the area where the brain enemy should be located,this is blocked by gameobject 194636 (braindoor), the brain enemy despawns and the fight is resetted / evaded (by Yogg probably because there is no one in range of Yogg as this is a solo run).

Is there any way to fix this by altering the `boss_yoggsaron.cpp` or another way?

Comment: Yes, that's the file of the boss script, which you would need to alter. I would try for a lot higher range and ignoring Los maybe for the reset checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have commented out the `EnterEvadeMode` in the `boss_yoggsaron.cpp` and this seems to work. You can now enter the brain portal without yogg evading and resetting the fight